# Kademlia XOR Distance as an Integer

Tags: encoding, p2p, xor, kademlia

In the Kademlia paper it mentions using the `XOR` of the `NodeID` interpreted as an integer. Let's pretend my `NodeID1` is `aaf4c61ddcc5e8a2dabede0f3b482cd9aea9434d` and my `NodeID2` is `ab4d8d2a5f480a137067da17100271cd176607a1`. What's the appropriate way to interpret this as an integer for comparison of `NodeID1` and `NodeID2`? Would I convert these into `BigInt` and `XOR` those two `BigInt`s? I saw that in one implementation. Could I also just convert each `NodeID` into decimal and `XOR` those values?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48602172/how-to-represent-kademlia-distance-metric-as-integer) question but I'm trying to better understand exactly how this works.

***Note: This isn't for implementation, I'm just trying to understand how the integer interpretation works.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic kademlia implementation you only need 2 bit arithmetic operations on the IDs: xor and comparison. For both cases the ID conceptually is a 160bit unsigned integer with overflow, i.e. modulo 2^160 arithmetic. It can be decomposed into a 20bytes or 5×u32 array, assuming correct endianness conversion in the latter case. The most common endianness for network protocols is big-endian, so byte 0 will contain the most significant 8 bits out of 160.

Then the xor or comparisons can be applied on a subunit by subunit basis. I.e. xor is just an xor for all the bytes, the comparison is a binary array comparison.

Using bigint library functions are probably sufficient for implementation but not optimal because they have size and signedness overhead compared to implementing the necessary bit-twiddling on fixed-sized arrays.

A more complete implementation may also need some additional arithmetic and utility functions.

> Could I also just convert each NodeID into decimal and XOR those values?

Considering the size of the numbers decimal representation is not particularly useful. For the human reader heaxadecimal or the individual bits are more useful and computers operates on binary and practically never on decimal.